# space doesn't push words in java eclipse when editing

Tags: java, eclipse, text-editor, eclipse-neon

I am trying to edit codes in java eclipse neon but i cant push words using the space button but instead it over rights  the next letters. how do i fix this.

For instance if i want to type the word `new` between the word `Object` and `rowData[][]` in the code below.

```
 Object rowData[][] = { { "Row1-Column1"...
```

The result will be

```
 Object newData[][] = { { "Row1-Column1"...
```

It does not push the other codes forward. it just over rights the next letters instead.

Comment: maybe your insert mode is on

Comment: Yea it has worked but i had to restart eclipse for it to work. I was wondering even after changing it. it couldn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try pressing the "Insert" button on your key board, my guess is you hit it by accident, I know it happens to me all the time. If you have a mac, I believe Fn and enter (the one from the numeric pad) keys combined should give same effect as the insert key so press that to reverse it. You may need to restart eclipse after pressing it, I know I sometimes have to do that as well.

Comment: Cosign, I did this all the time when I first started programming. I doubt you actually hit the insert key though, if your fingers or your keyboard are anything like mine, you probably hit '0' which doubles as Insert as mentioned.